# Delphi Handle in negative

Tags: delphi, handle, negative-number

I am working on a project in delphi XE5.
Different Popup menus are created at run time using same function.
Names are given each time to pop up using "Handle" from Tcomponent class.

```
popupname := 'XYZ' + IntToStr(handle);
```

On some system I get "Handle" value as negative, when I try to give name with "-" sign to a component i get error message
"XYZ-5645 not a valid component name"

Can you please suggest me a way out?

Comment: In XE3  `THandle = NativeUInt;`  Note unsigned type. How it is defined in XE5? Are you sure that handle value is negative?

Comment: @MBo IntToStr accepts signed int so there is an implicit cast to signed.

Comment: Although on XE7, the Int64 overload is selected first, so I think you need a 64 bit target before you could hit this condition........ Perhaps there are a different set of overloads in the XE5 RTL.

Comment: Since handle is unsigned you can use `UIntToStr(handle)` instead.

Comment: @LU not on x64, and since the type floats with pointer size, and is a pointer surely its best treated that way

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, but will the compiler not select the overloaded uint64 version on x64?

Comment: Er, maybe so.....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Looking into latest [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.THandle), `type THandle = Cardinal;` indicates that it does not float with pointer size. But docs have been wrong before.

Comment: Docs are wrong. Deep down it is void*

Comment: Yes I see that now. I'll make a report.

Comment: [THandle type is wrongly documented](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16295)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `IntToStr`, which accepts a signed integer, you can treat the handle as a pointer, and so represent the numeric value as hex:

```
popupname := Format('XYZ%p', [Pointer(Handle)]);
```

This makes sense because a handle in Windows is, as defined in the header files, an untyped pointer, `void*`.

As an added benefit your code will now be correct on both 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Thinking outside the box, perhaps the component does not need a name at all. If so, remove this code, leave it unmanned and thus side-step your problem.

Comment: @poonam Do take heed of the last sentence.  If you're compelled to give a runtime generated component a `.Name` to solve some sort of problem, it's extremely likely that it is simply the wrong solution and that there is a better way to produce the same behaviour.

Comment: "Untapped"? Did you mean "untyped"?

Comment: Yes I did mean that